# javascript onmouseover thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

is there anyway to enlarge the color swatch / that small attribute on mouse over? and I want to display the label of the selected attribute too in javascript?

My code is:

```
getOptionText: function(elem, value, config){
    var text = $(elem).innerHTML;
    var configType = this.getConfigValue(config, 'type', false);
    if (!configType) {
        return text;
    }
    switch (config.type) {
        case 'custom_images':
            var image = this.getConfigValue(config, 'images/' + value, false);
            if (image) {
                text = '<img src="' + image + '" alt="' + text +'" />';
            }
            break;
        case 'product_images':
            //get the images
            var imageAttribute = this.getConfigValue(config, 'product_images', '');
            var images = this.getConfigValue(this.config.images, imageAttribute, []);
            //get first allowed product
            var attrId = $(elem).parentNode.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');
            var options = this.getConfigValue(this.config.attributes, attrId + '/options', false);
            var productId = this.getFirstProductId(options, value);
            if (productId && (image = this.getConfigValue(images, productId, false))) {
                text = '<img src="' + image + '" alt="' + text +'" />';
            }
            break;
        case 'colors':
            var color = this.getConfigValue(config, 'color/' + value, false);
            if (color) {
                text = '<span class="switcher-hexacode" title="' + image + '" style="background-color:' + color +'"></span>'
            }
            break;
        default:
            text = this.handleCustomOptionText(text, elem, value, config);
            break;
    }
    return text;
},
```

something like in this image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to change the css classes of the of the smaller image to enlarge it, or to show a previously hidden larger image.

Using:

`$(//selector of your swatch).hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass(//a class that makes me big);
     },function(){
      $(this).removeClass(//the class just added);
     });`

Here's a fiddle showing the basic concept with a simple box http://jsfiddle.net/pjim/e8cjr8hz/

Hope that's helpful

Comment: thank you so much for your response, i'm not so good in jQuery, is there any way to implement this code in my code? can you do this? thank you so much